# Generalization of Hessians

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, optimization

Is there a generalization of Hessians in the same way that subgradients are a generalization of gradients?

Comment: There are several different generalizations of Hessian to functions which are noit twice differentiable. Search subhessian .